# Regex.MatchData returning null: why not Option[String]?

Tags: scala, null, nullreferenceexception

Is there any particular reason why Regex.MatchData.group(i: Int): java.lang.String returns null rather than Option[String]?

Is there a "Scala Way" to handle nulls in Scala?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It returns null because it is a shallow interface over the Java library. I think it sucks too, and I have been bitten by it.

If you get a value that may be null, you can write `Option(value)` on Scala 2.8 and it will become either `None` or `Some(value)`. That doesn't work with pattern matching, but you can write your own extractor for that:

```
object Optional {
  def unapply[T](a: T) = if (null == a) Some(None) else Some(Some(a))
}
```

Examples:

```
scala> val a:String = null
a: String = null

scala> a match {
     | case Optional(None) => println("Got none")
     | case Optional(Some(value)) => println("Got "+value)
     | }
Got none

scala> val a = "string"
a: java.lang.String = string

scala> a match {
     | case Optional(None) => println("Got none")
     | case Optional(Some(value)) => println("Got "+value)
     | }
Got string

scala> val a = "5"
a: java.lang.String = 5

scala> a match {
     | case Optional(None) => println("Got none")
     | case Optional(Some(value)) => println("Got "+value.toInt)
     | }
Got 5
```

Comment: I always forget to check those object definitions :) The pattern matching example is quite interesting.

Comment: Only one note: `Option(value)` works in Scala 2.8 only. Not 2.7.x

Comment: True enough. I was once better at tagging 2.8 stuff as such.