# Setting a regex optional group to None in Scala

Tags: regex, scala

I have the following regular expression pattern that matches fully qualified Microsoft SQL Server table names (`[dbName].[schemaName].[tableName]`), where the schema name is optional:

```
val tableNamePattern = """\[(\w+)\](?:\.\[(\w+)\])?\.\[(\w+)\]""".r
```

I am using it like this:

```
val tableNamePattern(database, schema, tableName) = fullyQualifiedTableName
```

When the schema name is missing (e.g.: `[dbName].[tableName]`), the `schema` value gets set to `null`.

Is there a Scala idiomatic way to set it to `None` instead, and to `Some(schema)` when the schemaName is provided?

> Some people, when confronted with a problem, think 
>   “I know, I'll use regular expressions.”   Now they have two problems.
>   -- Jamie Zawinski

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1842925/regex-matchdata-returning-null-why-not-optionstring

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to copy the code from the accepted answer on the linked question, and without giving credit too. Here it is:

```
object Optional {
  def unapply[T](a: T) = if (null == a) Some(None) else Some(Some(a))
}

val tableNamePattern(database, Optional(schema), tablename) = fullyQualifiedTableName
```

PS: I just today wondered on twitter whether creating special-case extractors was as common as they were suggested. :)

Comment: Makes me think of a (pseudocode follows) `extractor[T] Optional(a: T) = if (null == a) Some(None) else Some(Some(a))` macro of some sort :P

Comment: Is there a word for this tactic? "Double-dipping" doesn't quite cover it. Is that expr equivalent to `Some(Option(a))`? Only asking because DRY is even more important with code that is cut/pasted a lot. Noting of course that it still doesn't work in 2.7.x.

Comment: @som-snytt I think it is equivalent, yes.